# how to total every column php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 public function graph(Request $request) 
    {
        $statistics = DiraStatistics::whereBetween('date_access',array($request->from, $request->to))->get();

        $question_asked_sum = $statistics->sum('question_asked');
        $low_confidence_sum = $statistics->sum('low_confidence');
        $no_answer_sum = $statistics->sum('no_answer');
        $missing_intent_sum = $statistics->sum('missing_intent');

        return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('question_asked_sum', 'low_confidence_sum', 'no_answer_sum', 'missing_intent_sum'));
    }
```

[image]

Hey guys so i have done a function to total up the value of column for example "question_asked" between selected dates.. Now how can i also total up the row for example the first row in the picture so ( 9 + 1 + 4 + 7 ) = 21?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help like by query:

```
SELECT (SUM(questioned_asked)+SUM(low_confidence)+SUM(no_answer)+SUM(missing_intent)) as total FROM your_table
```

**OR**

```
SELECT (SUM(questioned_asked + low_confidence + no_answer + missing_intent)) as total FROM your_table
```

It will give like you said `( 9 + 1 + 4 + 7 ) = 21`

Comment: sorry i dont think its like that in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is by using a raw select statement in your query:

```
public function graph(Request $request)
{
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::select(DB::raw('sum(question_asked) as question_asked_sum, sum(low_confidence) as low_confidence_sum, sum(no_answer) as no_answer_sum, sum(missing_intent) as missing_intent_sum, sum(questions_asked + low_confidence + no_answer + missing_intent) as total_sum'))
        ->whereBetween('date_access', array($request->from, $request->to))
        ->get();

    $question_asked_sum = $statistics->question_asked_sum;
    $low_confidence_sum = $statistics->low_confidence_sum;
    $no_answer_sum = $statistics->no_answer_sum;
    $missing_intent_sum = $statistics->missing_intent_sum;
    $total_sum = $statistics->total_sum;

    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('question_asked_sum', 'low_confidence_sum', 'no_answer_sum', 'missing_intent_sum', 'total_sum'));
}
```

Also see [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) in the documentation.

Please note I haven't tested this. The result might be a Collection instead of an Object. Love to hear the result though so I can update to match!

Comment: Hi, i think you maybe you got my question wrong, what im trying to ask is now i have a form where a user able to select a start and end date and it display a chart.. So i want to be able to display the total amount of which is (question_asked+low_confidence+no_answer_missing_intent) to the user. Currently the user can see the total for each single column..In my blade: Questions Asked : <b>{!! $question_asked_sum !!}</b> <br> so i want the overall total of the 4 columns

Comment: I've updated the answer. Not sure if this is what you need, otherwise look at @hypernics answer?

Answer (score -1):

Create a method in DiraStatistics model class:

```
public function getSumnumsAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->question_asked + $this->low_confidence + $this->no_answer + $this->missing_intent;
}
```

Now your models give you the sum for $row->sumnums.

Or the aggregated $num_sum = $statistics->sum('sumnums');